# Sharepoint Restrict duplicate entry in List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, date-time

Guys Required support for below scenario. I have one list for booking with date and time. I want to restrict the duplicate entry by date and time.

I have tried the REST API code but it's not working. I need to check with two conditions date and time

Find below my code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PreSaveAction() {
        var check = false;
        var listid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
        var DateId = $('input[id*="Date_Req"]');
        
        $.ajax({
            url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listid + "')/items?$select=ID,Req_Date,Req_Time,Title&$orderby=ID desc&$filter=Date_Req eq  + DateId + ",
            type: 'GET',
            async: false,
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                var count = data.d.results.length;
                if (count < 2) {
                    check = true;
                } else {
                    alert('Dear Employee,no slot available');
                 ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/SiteAssets/Thank%20You.aspx}')
                }
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        })
    
       return check;
    }
```

Comment: I don't think using Date with **Time** alone in the filter criteria can eliminate duplicates. Because timestamps can be in milliseconds level. Do you have any other Field that you can use in the filter criteria?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to create a calculated column in your calendar list.
In the column's settings specify "Enforce unique values". Then you can use T[EXT, HOUR, and MINUTE functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v=office.14)) to create a value in the YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm format